# Visual Studio TFS Git not seeing any changes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm not getting something about Visual Studio's Git for TFS.

I cloned a colleague's solution in Git on TFS and started adding code. I then realised that I needed my own branch for the changes I was making, and so following the instructions in [Push a new local branch to a remote Git repo and track it too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6232535/575530) I ran

```
git checkout -b e4ctim
git push -u origin e4ctim
```

When I make changes to my code visual studio shows the familiar red-tick icon by the code file to reassure me that the change has triggered the file to be checked out:

[image: VS red-tick]

And then when I save the file the Visual Studio returns the icon to the blue padlock. I assume that this change from red-tick to blue padlock signifies that the change has been checked-in locally in Git:

[image: VS blue-lock]

But when I look at the history of the modified file, there is none!

[image: No history]

**I would like to commit my changes locally and sync them with the TFS server.**

Visual Studio does not see any changes at all:

[image: VS TFS Changes]

From the command line I can see that Git has noticed all of my modifications by running the command

```
git status
```

and seeing lots of changes not staged for commit and untracked files.

[image: git status cmd]

Looing at the [Git book](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) I could use

```
git add
```

or more specifically

```
git add -u .
```

to stage the files ready for a commit but I'm reluctant to do that as the [Develop your app in a Git repository (track, commit)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh967655) Visual Studio documentation states:

> Q: Where is the Git stage?
>   A: If you are an experienced Git user, you might have noticed that 
>   Visual Studio handles changes differently than the command prompt. 
>   You might have wondered if the Included Changes section contains 
>   your staged changes. In fact, Visual Studio usually bypasses the Git 
>   stage for you. When you commit changes, Visual Studio simultaneously 
>   stages and commits them. The one exception occurs when you add a 
>   file to your Git repository; Visual Studio does stage this kind of 
>   change.

**Visual Studio stages and commits changes simultaneously. But why is it not listing any of the modifications I have made to tracked files as changes, and thus letting me commit them?**

Comment: Note that I have deliberately not tagged this `git` yet as it seems peculiar to TFS and Visual Studio's Git workflow.

Comment: Are the files located under Team Explorer - Changes / Untracked files?

Comment: In the Visual Studio "15" preview, it now does use git's stage.

Comment: Cause of this is probably a previously unsuccessful commit, and all files in solution explorer becomes "committed". My cause of the problem was jmf-file added in SQL Server Database project (see below).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than an explanation, but I found that if I ignored [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh967655) "when you commit changes, Visual Studio simultaneously stages and commits them" and instead added the modifications to staging with the command

```
git add -u .
```

then Visual Studio suddenly became aware of the modifications and let me commit them locally and sync them with the TFS server. Moreover it then put the 'new file' green cross on the files I had added and I found I could do another commit and then another sync to pick up the additions and deletions I had made.

Since then Visual Studio is doing what I would expect: when I make a change to the file the file is listed as changed in the commit window.

I still do not know why Visual Studio failed to pick up the changes until after an initial `git add` but at least it works now.

Answer (score 15):

I had to add this line to my .gitignore:

```
[path to project]/node_modules/
```

Apparently VS2015 was crashing on some very long path in there and would just decide to give up all hope

Comment: Agreed. I just had this problem with an angular project. VS was choking on the node_modules and bower_components path and failing silently.

Comment: I had a similar problem, due to my home directory being on a remote server.  I have a shared drive (X:) to that same location and was able to open VS in such a way that Git worked.

Answer (score 10):

delete the file `myProject\.git\index.lock` fixed it in my case.

Comment: This worked for me in VS 2017, the problem occurred because the VS 2017 crashed while un-staging some files which must have left the `index.lock` file in the `.git` folder which in effect tells any program wanting to interact with the repository that it's already in use.

Comment: Same here. Deleted myProject\.git\index file. Then remove changes from branch (otherwise all files are marked as changed). And it works.

Comment: This is it. I deleted the index.lock file and boom!! i can see my changes now.

Comment: same fix worked for me. VS19 with gitlab

Answer (score 5):

I had the same probem and I realized the following:
In order to show the changeset, As @dumbledad said, Visual Studio runs the command

```
git add -u
```

internally for staging the updates. 
If some of the files that you are trying to add to your changeset is open by another process, then the git command gets a permission error. And Visual Studio won't show the changes.

In my case, I had a document in my repo that was open by another application, and that caused Visual Studio not to show the modifications because of the Git permission error. So check if any of the files of your git repository is not open by any other application.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VS 2015 Update 1 and also meet this problem. Furthermore, at the same time, the VS' output window told me my `VC.opendb` file under the solution folder is occupied by another program. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319008/git-issue-with-visual-studio-2015-update-1), I fixed the issue of occupying: add `*.VC.opendb` and `*.VC.db` to the `.gitignore` file. Then everything goes well.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Visual Studio Update 3. VS was saving locally but not picking up any changes so I couldn't commit.

I downloaded Git for Windows from https://git-for-windows.github.io/ (thanks @fhilton), opened the Developer Command Prompt and changed directory to C:\Repos\Scheduler (the location of my source code).

I then ran GET ADD -U and received the following error...

> error: open("WindowsServices\Scheduler.WindowServices.InstallLog"):
>   Permission Denied
>
> error: unable to index file
>   WindowsServices\Scheduler.WindowServices.InstallLog
>
> fatal: updating files failed

As others have said, it looks like the GIT tools in Visual Studio can fail silently, even for the most basic Windows level errors. Worse, it can tell you GIT is fully in sync. Command line is certainly your friend for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Open View > Output, select 'Source Control - Git' in Show Output from and check for any errors. As others mentioned, any error in Git makes MS Project silently ignore any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a new machine with a fresh install of both VS2013 Update 5 and VS 2015 and it was driving me crazy. Then I found if I installed Git for Windows, the problem went away!  https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Then i was trying to make changes but files doesn't get effected...There is a easy solution for this. The major problem is one of your git ignore files ignoring your files..

Open your local repo for instance D://repos, then look file you want

--> D://repos/project1/HomeViewModel.cs

--> Right click on it and click on Git Extentions

--> Choose +Add Files

[image]

--> then Force option

[image]

--> Click on Addfiles..Here you go you file will be added in changes

Answer (score 0):

Helpful article! Using Git Bash (git add -u) helped me get closer to the cause of the problem. After committing changes previously not shown in Visual Studio, only half-way commit was done because of using a SQL Server Database Project; Apparently, Windows 10 started to add jfm-files in the same folder keeping it open all the time and preventing it from beeing accessed by VS. Solution was to add it to the .gitignore before committing.

See this thread for further information:

[Visual Studio 2015 Database Project directory contains a file with extension jfm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704514/visual-studio-2015-database-project-directory-contains-a-file-with-extension-jfm)

Comment: .gitignore

*.jfm
*.dbmdl

Answer (score 0):

In my case my problem was I am using Linux with symbolic links in the path to my projec (cannot tell if windows with symbolic links has the same problem)