# Visual Studio 2022 source control not showing changes

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 not showing any change of file in git changes window, although there are some files updates are available. Whereas GIT GUI is showing all the changes in the repository.

Once I open the repository in GIT GUI all changes are also begin to display in Visual Studio git changes window.

Comment: Have the same problem...  making changes, but suddenly it's like there was an auto-commit and a push.

Comment: Same issue here with VS 2022 17.2.1. Solution was installing latest Git Bash. And adding back exception directory for the unsafe repository. `git config --global --add safe.directory C:/xxx/xxxx`

Comment: Same problem in VS2019 (I have already updated git to the latest version).

Comment: Im my case, the source control provider was not in Tools>Options>Source-Control. Setting it to "git" solved it.

Answer (score 11):

visual studio 2022 shows "error parsing the git status output.". It is maybe because of mismatched versions of git or visual studio.

as a workaround, in "Package Manager Console" you can run this command:

```
git status
```

after that, visual studio shows your changes, and you can commit them!

Comment: Funnily, this fixed several 'git' issues I was experiencing after upgrading to Visual Studio 2022.  Thank you!

Comment: Right, the versions' mismatch is the issue, VS detects git repo after updating git `git update-git-for-windows`

Comment: Running this command gave me a new suggested-command to add an Exception for the directory my repository was in, because it showed up with different owners (a.k.a. "_detected dubious ownership in repository_").  I ran the suggested-command, then ran `git status` one more time and it all worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. Then I found the answer under [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyrQcY4T-5U). Try this:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Path/To/Repo
```

Notice the forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I used to connect not `as admin`. Then in Git Repository Settings no remotes were displayed and at Git Changes there were only "create new" options.

Then I connected `as admin` and remotes become available, all were working as usual. Makes no sense to me but it's "working".

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the git index lock.  This solved my problem, deleting the index lock file: [Visual Studio: Git Team Explorer does not show any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053552/visual-studio-git-team-explorer-does-not-show-any-changes)

Comment: Deleting index lock file does not resolve my problem, after deleting index lock file it showing all files removed from repository rather than changes.

Answer (score 0):

**TL'DR**

Make sure both git and vs are up-to-date + use `git status` and if you got a *fatal: detected dubious ownership* error, then run `git config --global --add safe.directory '*'` and restart VS, finally, if none of these works and your local and remote copies are synced: delete the local copy and re-clone the repo again!

---

Possible Causes:

1. Git, VS Versions' mismatch: I have VS2022 up-to-date, but git-bash -> `git --version` was 7-versions old, so I have used git-bash -> `git update-git-for-windows` command to have an up-to-date version of git (you can download the 'git.exe' installer as an alternative).
   This shows git information in vs statusbar, but some solutions still not showing the git information! if this not works for you, try the next step..
2. In Visual Studio: View -> Other windows -> Package Manager Console, then type `git status`. In my case, it gives me a security fatal error!

   ```
   git : fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'path-to-solution'
   At line:1 char:1
   + git status
   .
   .
   ```

   To overcome this, I have used the following command to get rid of this issue forever: `git config --global --add safe.directory '*'`
3. If the project is relatively old, try re-cloning it again (if local and remote are synced, if not: delete the .git folder, clone the repo to a new folder, copy the .git folder from there and paste it in root folder, add and commit your changes).

Answer (score 0):

Look for bad filenames, particularly those not supported by Windows.

I encountered the problem of Visual Studio 2022 (specifically Version 17.7.4) not detecting changes. This was on a repo cloned using WSL onto a shared filesystem , in my case `mnt/c/workspace`. Oddly, things like `git status` *did* show there were changes.

The root cause turned out to be a bad filename in the root of the repository, specifically an [icon](https://github.com/gojimmypi/esp32-homekit-demo/blob/59a6252462e02ef5a4b4be5cc68f7083fd222d3f/Icon%0D) name with a carriage return in the name.

I was able to find this by using the `View-Other Windows-Package Manager` and running `git status` there.

Alternatively, cloning the repo directly to the Windows/DOS file system can also be used to detect the problematic file. Any serious problems will cause the clone to fail. WSL of course does not have a problem with this, but Visual Studio 2022 did not expect it. There was otherwise no error.